# Notes will not delete

Tags: ios, swift

I have a note part of my app which I am able to create note and edit notes but when it comes to deleting notes I have an issue. I can delete them from the table view itself and all notes but when I reload the app they're back as if they're sticking in the dictionary. Could you pleas etell me a way to delete them permanently. I have three controllers, only two being relevant. Here are the relevant ones:

MasterViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class MasterViewController: UITableViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var menuButton: UIBarButtonItem!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    Note.loadnotes()
    noteTable = self.tableView
    // Side Menu
    if self.revealViewController() != nil {
        menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()
        menuButton.action = "revealToggle:"
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
    }
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

func insertNewObject(sender: AnyObject) {
    allNotes.insert(Note(), atIndex: 0)
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
    self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showDetail", sender: self)
}

// MARK: - Segues

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
            let object: Note = allNotes[indexPath.row] as Note
            currentNoteIndex = indexPath.row
        }
        else {
            currentNoteIndex = 0
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - Table View

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return allNotes.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    let object: Note = allNotes[indexPath.row]
        as Note;    cell.textLabel!.text = object.note
    return cell
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {
        allNotes.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    } else if editingStyle == .Insert {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
    }
}


}
```

note.swift

```
import UIKit

var allNotes:[Note] = []
var currentNoteIndex:NSInteger = -1
var noteTable:UITableView?

let KAllNotes:String = "notes"


class Note: NSObject {
var date:String
var note:String

override init() {
    date = NSDate().description
    note = ""
}

func dictionary() -> NSDictionary {
    return ["note":note, "date":date]
}

class func saveNotes() {
    var aDictionaries:[NSDictionary] = []
    for (var i:NSInteger = 0; i < allNotes.count; i++) {
        aDictionaries.append(allNotes[i].dictionary())
    }
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(aDictionaries, forKey: KAllNotes)
    //        aDictionaries.writeToFile(filePath(), atomically: true)
}

class func loadnotes() {
    var defaults:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    var savedData:[NSDictionary]? = defaults.objectForKey(KAllNotes) as? [NSDictionary]
    //        var savedData:NSArray? = NSArray(contentsOfFile: filePath())
    if let data:[NSDictionary] = savedData {
        for (var i:NSInteger = 0; i < data.count; i++) {
            var n:Note = Note()
            n.setValuesForKeysWithDictionary(data[i] as [NSObject : AnyObject])
            allNotes.append(n)
        }
    }
}

class func filePath() -> String {
    var d:[String]? = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.AllDomainsMask, true) as? [String]
    if let directories:[String] = d {
        var docsDirectory:String = directories[0]
        var path:String = docsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("\(KAllNotes).notes")
        return path;
    }
    return ""
}
}
```

Thanks in advance
Sam

Comment: 1) Please narrow down all of the code to just the part relevant to the deletion issue. 2) Where do you attempt to persist the data after deleting a note?

Comment: In MasterViewController the last override func is the delete section

Comment: Are you saving the notes in documents directory on save? What does KAllNotes.notes files contain

Comment: KAllNotes contains the variables note and date I think. the notes are saving to persistant storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the master view controller use this altered function:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {
        allNotes.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        Note.saveNotes()
    } else if editingStyle == .Insert {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
    }
}
```

This will force the dictionary to be re-saved. using your save notes function in notes.swift