# Add initial note

Tags: ios, swift

I am looking at adding an inital note to the note page within my app. this is so that when people click to the notes part there will be some detail on how to use it rather than just a big empty screen. I have no idea where to implement this though. Could you please help, below is the page where it talks about the dictionaries.

```
import UIKit
import MessageUI

class DetailViewController: UIViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate, UITextViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var tView: UITextView!
@IBAction func BarButton(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        let textToShare = ""

        if let myWebsite = NSURL(string: "")
        {
            let objectsToShare = [textToShare, myWebsite]
            let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)

            self.presentViewController(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

    OpenMail()
}

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    tView.text = (allNotes[currentNoteIndex] as Note).note
    tView.becomeFirstResponder()
    // Set controller as swipe gesture recogniser, to allow keyboard dismissal for text box
    var swipe: UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "dismissKeyboard")

    swipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Down

    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipe)
    self.tView.delegate = self

}

 override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    if tView.text == "" {
        allNotes.removeAtIndex(currentNoteIndex)
    }
    else {
        (allNotes[currentNoteIndex] as Note).note = tView.text
    }
    Note.saveNotes()
    noteTable?.reloadData()
}

 override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func configuredMailComposeViewController() -> MFMailComposeViewController {
    // Open mail controller on screen and prepare with preset values.
    let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
    var MessageText: String!
    MessageText = tView.text
    mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self
    mailComposerVC.setToRecipients([""])
    mailComposerVC.setSubject("")
    mailComposerVC.setMessageBody(MessageText, isHTML: false)

    return mailComposerVC
}

func showSendMailErrorAlert() {
    // Alert user to email error
    let sendMailErrorAlert = UIAlertView(title: "Could Not Send Email", message: "Your device could not send e-mail.  Please check e-mail configuration and try again.", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
    sendMailErrorAlert.show()
}

// MARK: MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate Method
func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController!, didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError!) {
    controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}


func OpenMail() {
    //Function to open mail composer on screen

    let mailComposeViewController = configuredMailComposeViewController()
    if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
        self.presentViewController(mailComposeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        self.showSendMailErrorAlert()
    }

}
func dismissKeyboard() {
    // Dismiss keyboard for textfield
    self.tView.resignFirstResponder()

}


}
```

note.swift

```
import UIKit

var allNotes:[Note] = []
var currentNoteIndex:NSInteger = -1
var noteTable:UITableView?

let KAllNotes:String = "notes"


class Note: NSObject {
var date:String
var note:String

override init() {
    date = NSDate().description
    note = ""
}

func dictionary() -> NSDictionary {
    return ["note":note, "date":date]
}

class func saveNotes() {
    var aDictionaries:[NSDictionary] = []
    for (var i:NSInteger = 0; i < allNotes.count; i++) {
        aDictionaries.append(allNotes[i].dictionary())
    }
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(aDictionaries, forKey: KAllNotes)
    //        aDictionaries.writeToFile(filePath(), atomically: true)
}

class func loadnotes() {
    allNotes.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
    var defaults:NSUserDefaults =   NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    var savedData:[NSDictionary]? = defaults.objectForKey(KAllNotes) as? [NSDictionary]
    //        var savedData:NSArray? = NSArray(contentsOfFile: filePath())
    if let data:[NSDictionary] = savedData {
        for (var i:NSInteger = 0; i < data.count; i++) {
            var n:Note = Note()
            n.setValuesForKeysWithDictionary(data[i] as [NSObject : AnyObject])
            allNotes.append(n)
        }
    }
}

class func filePath() -> String {
    var d:[String]? = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.AllDomainsMask, true) as? [String]
    if let directories:[String] = d {
        var docsDirectory:String = directories[0]
        var path:String = docsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("\(KAllNotes).notes")
        return path;
    }
    return ""
}
```

}

Thanks in advance
Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an NSUserDefault boolean that stores whether or not the initial note should be shown, e.g. that the app has been launched for the first time. Then load an initial note accordingly. When a note is added or the initial note is deleted, then change the boolean accordingly so the initial note doesn't show up next time.

You could also initialize your database with an initial note. Not clear from your code how the notes are saved, but this approach would probably rely on the NSUserDefault approach above, except it could be done in the AppDelegate or something.

example:

```
let InitialSetupComplete = "InitialSetupComplete"   // Note: I would define this at the top of a file
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
if defaults.boolForKey(InitialSetupComplete) {
    // Show initial note
}

// Later on when the note is deleted, or modified (or immediately after initial note loaded into the database, see below)
defaults.setBool(true, forKey: InitialSetupComplete)
```

Would be easier/cleaner just to initialize your database with the initial note in the app delegate (e.g. call within applicationDidFinishLaunching), so your view controller doesn't have to figure this out. Similar code, except you would use setBool right away after the initial note has been saved to the database. I don't know anything about your database from the question, so can't really provide a more detailed example than this. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Shim, still having some issues with this have added it into the notes VC and also tried it in app delegate but not seeing the initial note. in this link are some of my other swift files regarding the notes. Might help you understand how im saving http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29831597/notes-will-not-delete

Comment: You're saving all the notes in NSUserDefaults?

Comment: It might work, but it's not really what it's intended for and it's bad practice. Better to use Core Data or at least store it in a plist

Comment: Anyway, would need to see what you're doing to help you any further

Comment: Notes.swift that contains the dictionary is now in the original post.

Comment: Saw that in the link. I was referring to where you're setting up the initial note.